# Can't install module using composer on Magento 2.1

Tags: composer-php, magento2.1, m2e-pro

I am trying to install **M2ePro** module on my **Magento ver. 2.1.8** application using composer and getting this error:

```
[http]$ php-7.0 /usr/local/bin/composer require m2e/ebay-amazon-magento2
```

> Could not find a matching version of package m2e/ebay-amazon-magento2.
>   Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the
>   package is available in a stability which matches your
>   minimum-stability (alpha).

The spelling of the package is correct, I have tried defining the version of the module (The only one available is 1.3.2):

```
[http]$ php-7.0 /usr/local/bin/composer require m2e/ebay-amazon-magento2:1.3.2
```

However get the same error so I believe stability of this module is "`Beta`" and I have "`minimum-stability (alpha)`" set so beta modules should be installed with no problems.?

I looked for solution in composer docs but could find anything about installing beta: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require

Or was I looking in the wrong place?

I managed to successfully install the module on my development site and didn't receive this error so I thought it might be due to the fact that my Magento application was in the "Production" mode but setting the mode to "Developer" did not solve my problem.

UPDATE:

I just found this thread: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114393/error-in-using-composer-to-install-a-module-in-magento-2-0. The answer to this question is that you need to  define the package as repository. The package is from marketplace and this is content of my composer.json:

```
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"prefer-stable": true,
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    }       
],
```

I have previously installed modules from marketplace using composer with no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It came out that my `auth.json` had incorrect credentials and couldn't find the account.

Correcting the account settings fixed my problem.

Comment: you saved my file once

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i just encountered same problem with you and got the solution from you, it took me 3 hours

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped. I spend sometime trying to figure it out myself :/